# SQL: Replace Part Of a String in a Column for every row

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I have a Table. For sake of argument I called it Table. In the Table, I have Three Column.
Columns(Pkey,Name,ID,Location).

```
   **PKey**      **Name**                         **ID**        **Location**
     1         Penn State Main - 1551             1234             01
     2         Penn State Branch - 1551           2345             02  
     3         Florida State - 1661               3456             03 
     4         Florida State Branch -1661         4567             04
```

I want to replace the values after the dash(-) with the ID+'-'+Location for all rows

I have this so far:

```
BEGIN
declare @name1 varchar(50),@name varchar(50),@ID char(4), @location char(2)
declare @IDLocation varchar(6),@loop int

set @loop=0
set @IDLocation=''
set @name1=''

DECLARE _cursor cursor for
    select name,ID,location from Table
OPEN _cursor

FETCH _cursor 
into @name, @ID, @location

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
set @IDLocation = @ID+'-'+@location
if @loop !=0
Begin
    Select SUBSTRING(@name,1,CHARINDEX('-',@name)-1)
End
    set @name1= @name+'-'+ @IDLocation
    set @loop= @loop + 1

    Fetch _cursor 
    into @name, @ID, @location
End
close _cursor
deallocate _cursor
END
```

Summary. I really did give effort. I execute this  and nothing does not change it remains the same value you see above. By adding the substring, I though i would be able to remove everything after the (-) then later  add strings to it.

PLEASE ASSIST ME. IT WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. thanks to anyone who tried to help.
First I had a few things wrong. For those who want to learn
Since I already have a while@@ fetch i don't really need the loop

```
    BEGIN
declare @subname varchar(70),@name1 varchar(50),@name varchar(50),@ID char(4), @location char(2)
declare @pkey int,@IDLocation varchar(6)

set @IDLocation=''
set @name1=''

DECLARE _cursor cursor for
    select pkey,name,ID,location from Table
OPEN _cursor

FETCH _cursor 
into @pkey, @name, @ID, @location

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
set @IDLocation = @ID+'-'+@location


    Select @subname= SUBSTRING(@name,1,CHARINDEX('-',@name)-1)

    set @name1= @subname+'-'+ @IDLocation

    Update Table set name=@name1
    where pkey=@pkey


    Fetch _cursor 
    into @pkey, @name, @ID, @location
End
close _cursor
deallocate _cursor
END
```